# What does regex [\0-\uffff] capture?

Tags: javascript, regex

As I am reading through someone else's JavaScript, I encountered this regex charset:

```
[\0-\uffff]
```

What exactly is captured by this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That logical group will match every Unicode character between `null` and `0xffff`

Nothing will actually be captured. For that you will have to use `(` and `)`

Comment: Thanks. This might sound dumb, but is that all the unicode chars in UTF-8?

Comment: It contains all the valid UTF-8 Characters in addition to a large amount of other data

Answer (score 1):

The set of characters whose code is within `0` to `0xffff`.